# How do I specify methods to run only before a certain group of tests in PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit

The PHPUnit documentation makes mention of the @before annotation, which allows you to specify methods to run before each test case. Is there a way to specify an @before so that it only runs before test cases that are in a specific group?

So, if I have a test suite where all tests are in "@group A" or "@group B", can I use @before in a way to specify an @before specifically for "@group A" tests?

Comment: I would separate your tests into logical folders, and then do a test plan.  Each test file can have a setUp() and tearDown() which will do work before a test and after.  Making your tests, smaller, atomic units will be better in the long run, and try to reduce your dependency on outside settings, requirements.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I think in my use case I was imagining how many of these tests are going to be neutral to group A and group B (meaning, they apply to both groups). In which case, I wanted to avoid re-writing tests as much as possible. But this might just be necessary for good test writing.